# Finding all largest sequences

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, cluster-computing, data-mining

What would be an appropriate algorithm or strategy to cluster the patterns in a multidimensional array of numbers in which the elements have different lengths.

An example would be an array with these elements:

```
0: [4,2,8,5,3,2,8]
1: [1,3,6,2]
2: [8,3,8]
3: [3,2,5,2,1,8]
```

The goal is to find and cluster the patterns inside those lists of numbers. For instance in element "3" there is the pattern: "2,5,2,8" (not contiguous) which can also be found in element "0".
The numbers of the pattern found are not contiguous either in element "0" nor in element "3", but they have the same order.

Note: the example uses integers for more clarity but the real data will use floats, and instead of being exactly the same they will be taken as a "match" when both are separate within a given threshold.

.

**Edit 2:**
Although Abhishek Bansai's way is helpful if we chose only the longest common subsequence, we may miss other important patterns. For instance the these two sequences:

```
0: [4,5,2,1,3,6,8,9]
1: [2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

The longest common subsequence would be [2,1,3,6,8] but there is another important subsequence [4,5,6,8] that we would be missing.

.

**Edit 1:**
The answer from Abhishek Bansai seems a very good way to go about this.

It's the [Longest Common Subsequence algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem):

Comparing each element with each of the other elements using this algorithm will return all the patterns, and the next step would be to generate clusters out of those patterns.

Comment: I guess you want the longest common subsequence algorithm. Google for it.

Comment: That seems to be the way to go. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: The longest common subsequence is good although check "Edit 2" that describes a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be more interested in finding a "likeness" between sequences by looking for all the matches (per edits 1,2), you'll find that there is a vast body of research in the field of [Sequence Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment). From the wiki:

> In bioinformatics, a sequence alignment is a way of arranging the sequences of DNA, RNA, or protein to identify regions of similarity that may be a consequence of functional, structural, or evolutionary relationships between the sequences. Aligned sequences of nucleotide or amino acid residues are typically represented as rows within a matrix. Gaps are inserted between the residues so that identical or similar characters are aligned in successive columns.